# Query for Inner Join of 3 tables and get avg of result

Tags: sql

I am using  three tables `students`, `student_class` and `class`. I am using an inner join and partly getting the result i would like. My issue is performing an inner join with an average on a result based in three tables. How can i get the average GPA of students in Basic Calculus? sql

TABLES

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM Students;

STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME                                        SCHOOL_ID        GPA
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
         2 FREDDY FROST                                            11546       1.22
         3 Frank Smith                                             11111       3.21
         4 Rob S. Frost                                            11111          4
         5 Sam John SMITH                                          11111        3.2
         6 Sally SAvage                                            11546       3.54
         7 Bart W. SImpson                                         11111       2.12
         8 Franklin Q. Kafka                                       11111        3.2
         9 Jacky Frost                                             11111       1.22
        10 fran smith                                              11546       3.21
        11 Ronda Frost                                            123134          4
        12 Samuel Smith                                            11111        3.2
        13 PAT SAMSON                                             123134       3.54
        14 Bart Simpson                                           123134       2.12
        15 JOHN Brown                                              11546        3.2
        16 Robby Lee                                              123134       1.22
        17 ABE FRANKS                                             123134       3.21
        18 Robert Frost                                            11546          4
        19 SAM Smith                                               11111        3.2
        20 Fred SAvage                                             11546       3.54
        21 Bart Simpson                                           123134       2.12
        22 Frank Kafka                                             11546        3.2

21 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT * FROM Class;

  CLASS_ID CLASS_NAME          TEACHER_ID MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE
---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Intro to ALGEBRA            11                  12
         2 Basic CALCULUS               2                  10
         3 ABC and 123                  1                  15
         4 Sharing 101                  8                  10
         5 Good Talk, Bad Talk          9                  20
         6 Nap Time                     1                  21
         7 WRITing 101                  5                  10
         8 Finger Painting              9                  14
         9 Physics 230                  2                  20
        10 Gym                          5                  25

10 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT * FROM STUDENT_CLASS;

  CLASS_ID STUDENT_ID
---------- ----------
         2         12
         2         11
         2          2
         2          7
         2          8
         2         16
         2         21
         7         10
         7          2
         7          3
         7          4
         7          5
         7          6
         7          7
         7          8
         7          9
         9          2
         9         11
         9         12
         9         13
         9         14
         9         15
         9         16
         9         17
         9         18
         9         20
         9         21
         9         22
        10         12
        10          4
        10          3
        10          6
        10          8
        10          9
        10         12
        10         16
        10         18
        10         20
        10          2
        10          4

40 rows selected.


SQL> SELECT s.GPA,c.Class_Name,s.Student_ID,sc.Student_ID,sc.Class_ID,c.Class_ID From Students s INNER JOIN Student_c
lass sc ON sc.student_id = s.student_id INNER JOIN Class c ON c.class_ID = sc.class_ID where Upper(c.Class_name)= 'BA
SIC CALCULUS';

       GPA CLASS_NAME          STUDENT_ID STUDENT_ID   CLASS_ID   CLASS_ID
---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       3.2 Basic CALCULUS              12         12          2          2
         4 Basic CALCULUS              11         11          2          2
      1.22 Basic CALCULUS               2          2          2          2
      2.12 Basic CALCULUS               7          7          2          2
       3.2 Basic CALCULUS               8          8          2          2
      1.22 Basic CALCULUS              16         16          2          2
      2.12 Basic CALCULUS              21         21          2          2

7 rows selected.
```

Query

```
SQL> SELECT s.GPA,c.Class_Name,s.Student_ID,sc.Student_ID,sc.Class_ID,c.Class_ID From Students s INNER JOIN Student_c
lass sc ON sc.student_id = s.student_id INNER JOIN Class c ON c.class_ID = sc.class_ID where Upper(c.Class_name)= 'BA
SIC CALCULUS'
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Please add desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to class name and average GPA as output, you just need to use the `avg()` function and group by class name:

```
SELECT c.Class_Name, AVG(s.GPA) AS Avg_GPA
FROM Students s 
INNER JOIN Student_class sc ON sc.student_id = s.student_id 
INNER JOIN Class c ON c.class_ID = sc.class_ID 
WHERE UPPER(c.Class_name)= 'BASIC CALCULUS'
GROUP BY c.Class_Name
```

This would be the result:

```
|     Class_Name | Avg_GPA |
|----------------|---------|
| Basic CALCULUS |    2.44 |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d013/1)